# Why does this C function not return an integer value?

Tags: c, function

When I try to execute my program, I get an error. I can't read the last value in "`ch`":

```
int choi(char *Tvide[48])//permet de choisir la place selon les choix de l utilisateur
{
    char fum, classe, pos;

    printf("\n S.V.P choisissez votre Classe   (A:1 ere classe )/(B: 2 eme classe): ");
    classe = getche();
    printf("\n Est ce que vous etes fumeur   (O:fumeur)/(N:non fumeur):");
    fum = getche();
    printf("\n S.V.P vous preferez s''assoir pres de la fenetre ou du couloir(C:couloir )/(F:fenetre):");
    pos=getche();

    int Tfum[24] = {3,4,7,8,11,12,15,16,19,20,23,24,27,28,31,32,35,36,39,40,43,44,47,48};
    int Tnfum[24] = {1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22,25,26,29,30,33,34,37,38,41,42,45,46};
    int Tfen[24] = {1,4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17,20,21,24,25,28,29,32,33,36,37,40,41,44,45,48};
    int Tcol[24] = {2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31,34,35,38,39,42,43,46,47};
    int k;

    char Tdispo[48];

    for(k=1; k<=48; k++) { Tdispo[k]='o'; } // on met içi le tableau des places vides

    if (classe=='A')
    {
        for(k=9;k<=48;k++) { Tdispo[k]='n'; }
    }
    if (classe=='B')
    {
        for(k=1;k<=9;k++) { Tdispo[k]='n'; } 
    }
    if (fum=='O')
    {
        for(k=1;k<=24;k++) { Tdispo[Tnfum[k]]='n'; }
    }
    if (fum=='N')
    {
        for(k=1;k<=24;k++) { Tdispo[Tfum[k]]='n'; } 
    }
    if (pos=='C')
    {
        for(k=1;k<=24;k++) { Tdispo[Tfen[k]]='n'; }
    }
    if (pos=='F')
    {
        for(k=1; k<=24; k++) { Tdispo[Tcol[k]]='n'; }
    }

    int s;

    printf("Les places disponibles sont:");

    for(s=1; s<=48; s++)
    {
        if(Tdispo[s] == 'o') { printf("%d",s,"~"); }
    }

    int ch;
    printf("\n S.V.P introduire votre choix :");
    scanf("%d",ch);

    Tvide[ch]=='n';
    int ch1 = ch;
    return ch1;
}
```

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Could you please try to format this post a little better?

Comment: Don't post commented out code. Post a minimal, self-contained program that still exhibits the problem. Try to use standard C functions where applicable or specify compiler/platform combination.

Comment: You are far more likely to get helpful answers if you simplify the problem that you are trying to solve. Specifically, boil your problem down to be as simple as possible. Explain what you're trying to do, what it is you are expecting to happen, and what you are actually seeing. Most people will see your ream of code and click their back button and move on to a different question.

Comment: Consider reformatting your question so that it isn't complete illegible. Also try to break your function down to the simplest possible set of code that exhibits the issue. And also perhaps explain what the code is *supposed* to do.

Comment: And yet, someone was able to provide the likely solution to his question. Sure the OP could have been more succinct, but maybe you guys would be getting the rep if you'd bothered to figure it out instead of snidely regurgitating the FAQ.

Comment: What are these two adjacent lines for (at the bottom of your code)? int ch1 = ch; return ch1;

Comment: @Ben: Not all of us are repwhores. This is not a place to dump your code and have other people fix it.

Comment: @Ben M: I'll hazard a guess that this poster has not read the FAQ. I'll also assert that our comments are neither snide nor regurgitated and they are potentially helpful.

Comment: @Ben M: Learning how to ask a question is an important life (and SO) skill. We are all offering *constructive* suggestions on how to make the question clearer. Just because you *can* decrypt what was written doesn't mean that posters shouldn't *try* to ask their questions in a reasonably straightforward way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have

```
scanf("%d",&ch);
```

not

```
scanf("%d",ch);
```

Because the result of scanf gets stored **in** the variable named `ch`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that C uses 0-based arrays. A array of size 24 iss accessed 0 to 23) but you access them from 1 to 24, thus the last access is outside the array.